# How to make 'search box which shows list of dynamic option according to data retrieve by get api call on input string' like select2 in amp mail

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I am very new in AMP Email technology and I am facing an issue related to render dynamic options inside search box which makes get API request call as query according to input string and show options list according to data retrieve by request.

I came to know that amp-autocomplete is not working in amp-email and I use this code. So, please consider this and suggest a way how to solve this problem.

```
    <div>
      <amp-state id="name"></amp-state>
      <input id="name-input" placeholder="Search name..." on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({ name: event.value })">
      <amp-list layout="fixed-height" height="100" src="https://www.example.com/a/b?q='name'" items=".">
        <template type="amp-mustache">
          <div>{{name}}</div>
        </template>
      </amp-list>
    </div>
```

This code shows a input field but on writing on it I can't get any list.

Result of get request of "https://www.example.com/a/b?q=a" gives json data like this [{"id": "1", "name": "abc"}, {"id": "2", "name": "abd"}, ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to modify the `src` of an amp-list, but AMP for Email doesn't allow binding to `src` (also, you'd have to use `[src]` instead of `src` to do this in AMP on the web).

One option is to use `amp-form` with a hidden input field that you submit as soon as you call `setState`:

```
<div>
  <input id="name-input" placeholder="Search name..." on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({ name: event.value }), suggestions.submit">

  <form id="suggestions" method="get" action-xhr="https://www.example.com/a/b">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="" [value]="name">
    <div submit-success>
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{#.}}
        <div>{{name}}</div>
        {{/.}}
      </template>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also note that you don't need `<amp-state>` unless you want to give your state a default value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I really appreciate this. Requests are gone on every character entry and it is going like this "https://www.example.com/a/b/?q=a&__amp_source_origin=amp%40gmail.dev". Actually, my site request is not compatible with cors. Is there any way we can make same source request with csrf token or I have to do some other thing?. Can you please guide me through this?

Comment: There's no workaround for CORS, you'll need to make sure your website sends the right headers.

Comment: Hi, I have declared response header like this: Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin = amp@gmail.dev, Access-Control-Expose-Headers = AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin, when it hits request I can see data in Inspect element/Network but I can't see any data on screen and I have also mention submit-error along with submit-success but it isn't going in any of this. Please guide me how can I proceed with this?