# what is correct way of get amp-form and response headers?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I want to make search box which dynamically shows options according to input. In order to do this I asked question which can be found here :- [How to make 'search box which shows list of dynamic option according to data retrieve by get api call on input string' like select2 in amp mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182931/how-to-make-search-box-which-shows-list-of-dynamic-option-according-to-data-ret)

This is my implementation

```
      <input id="name-input" placeholder="Search name..." on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({ name: event.value }), suggestions.submit">
      <form id="suggestions" method="get" action-xhr="https://example.com/a/b">
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value="" [value]="name">
        <div submit-success>
          success
          <template type="amp-mustache">
            {{#.}}
            <div>{{name}}</div>
            {{/.}}
          </template>
        </div>
        <div submit-error>
          error
        </div>
      </form>
```

and implemented these response headers

response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"

response.headers["AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"] = "amp@gmail.dev"

response.headers["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"] = "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"

In my network, I am getting response data but on screen I can't see anything neither success nor error and getting these errors

b.setAttribute is not a function. (In 'b.setAttribute("i-amphtml-rendered","")', 'b.setAttribute' is undefined)

and

Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: b.setAttribute is not a function. (In 'b.setAttribute("i-amphtml-rendered","")', 'b.setAttribute' is undefined)